# Import data (arrays) to Quicksight

Tags: postgresql, amazon-quicksight

How can I import arrays data into Quicksight from Postgresql? For example {1,2,3,4,5}. I tried to import all data into Quicksight but it doesn't recognize the arrays. However, if I download as csv from Postgresql and then import local csv file to Quicksight, it will recognize the arrays as string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array_join**(array,';'). This will show your array element in quick sight with ; separated like [1;2;3;4;5]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried converting the data type using a custom SQL command that will convert the array? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/adding-a-SQL-query.html

```
SELECT column_name->'name' AS name
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved that with custom SQL + unnest() on the column with array, difference is that later you will have to keep in mind that some rows are not unique